# product page some functionality lost - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product, theme

I have created theme which extends to luma, right now I am customizing home page by the help of customize widget.After setting new theme I have faced two problems

**1) category url show none of the product**

for example when I load `<magento-root>`/women.html

it will show **You have no items to compare.**

[image: easy for your reference]

**2) product detail page**

till Yesterday everything going fine, but suddenly I have lost product page some functionality like

- detail,more information,review tab not working
- review form only show field(no text)
- related products shown nothing

[image: review form]

**Related Product**

[image: related products]

**But I am very sure, I am not touching any product page customization from (Magento_Catalog).**

how to sort out from this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` ?

Comment: no. what does this command?

Comment: @Bill  run your command  after some google, but no luck. still the same problem remain